# Vanilla Javascript for creating an array from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, leaflet

```
var cityMarkers = [
    {
        id: "bliss",
        name: "Principality of Bliss",
        icon: cityIcon,
        coords: [-90.19, -76.90]
    },
    {
        id: "cantonia",
        name: "Grand City of Cantonia",
        icon: cityIcon,
        coords: [-39.513421, -69.09375]
    },
    {
        id: "mithril",
        name: "Grand City of Mithril ",
        icon: cityIcon,
        coords: [42, -102.5]
    }];
```

I have the above in a separate file for referencing from my app.js file.

```
  cityMarkers.forEach(function(item) {
      var marker = L.marker(item.coords, {icon : item.icon});
      marker.bindTooltip("<b>" + item.name + "<b>", {permanent: true, offset: 
  [60, 0]});
```

This will make the markers and the other properties, but it won't put them on the map. An array handles placing them on the map, so this doesn't help me much with  what I am really trying to do.

This is a map based on the leaflet library. I am trying to assign a variable to each city with the id. Then, after the markers are made and attached to their variables, I want to make an array out of those names to function as the data layer. I admit that I am out of my depth, here. Any guidance would be most appreciated. I linked the documentation below in case anyone wants it.

https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html

I did research the question, but I was unable to find any results that answered what I think I am asking. I would highly prefer a nudge over a flat answer. I don't understand how to instantiate the variables and bind them to the markers. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding the markers directly to the map, add them to a `L.layerGroup`. You can add the `layerGroup` to the map and remove it again at will.

```
var lg = new L.layerGroup();
cityMarkers.forEach(function(item) {
      var marker = L.marker(item.coords, {icon : item.icon});
      marker.bindTooltip("<b>" + item.name + "<b>", {permanent: true, offset: 
  [60, 0]})
  .addTo(lg)});

lg.addTo(map);       // Add the layerGroup the map
lg.removeFrom(map);  // Remove the layerGroup from the map
```

Comment: Hmm. That worked. I'm confused, though. I thought it wouldn't work because the array values wouldn't have unique variables. I thought that was important when referencing the layer to include in my control for toggling all cities. So, I guess my real question is how do array values get assigned when creating them from a loop? Thanks for the answer by the way!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try adding `.addTo(map)`

```
cityMarkers.forEach(function(item) {
  var marker = L.marker(item.coords, {icon : item.icon});
  marker
    .bindTooltip("<b>" + item.name + "<b>", {permanent: true, offset: [60, 0]})
    .addTo(map);
```

[Demo for adding multiple markers to leaflet.](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/9150014)

Comment: Yes, it will add them to the map, but they won't be in a layer which enables them to be toggled.

Comment: params *permanent* true is making them stay on the map.
can you check this out https://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/2875/

Comment: Params permanent is a toolTip option. It makes the text permanent, not the marker.

Comment: For clarity, permanent and offset are part of the options object which  is part of the bindtoolTip() method. Regardless, thanks for taking the time to respond.